# Eclipse Project Name Validation

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

Why eclipse allows a project to be created with special characters in it name? I can create project with name '!#$!#!#@$!@#$'

Even the eclipse source of eclipse consider only following characters as invalid for project name.

```
INVALID_RESOURCE_CHARACTERS = new char[] {'\\', '/', ':', '*', '?', '"', '<', '>', '|'};
```

What is the logic behind it? are those characters having any special meaning for eclipse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the project name is used as the root folder name for all resources in the project.  That's what drives the naming restrictions.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris. This really helped. In source code I also found a link describing the same. Basically they are treating project as any other file system folder. INVALID_RESOURCE_CHARACTERS are the only restricted characters for a folder name to be valid. :) :) Thanks once again :)